# Error trying to open json file [json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes]

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm trying to open a `json` file using the `json library` in `Python 3.8` but I have not succeeded.

This is my MWE:

```
with open(pbit_path + file_name, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

where `pbit_path` and `file_name` is the absolute path of the `.json` file. As an example, this is a sample of the `.json` file that i'm trying to open.

```
https://github.com/pwnaoj/desktop-tutorial/blob/master/DataModelSchema.json
```

Error returned

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I have also tried using the functions `loads()`, `dump()`, `dumps()`.

I appreciate any suggestions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. In principle, it is an encoding problem since the type of file I am trying to read is encoded with `UCS-2`, so in `python`

```
with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf_16_le') as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = json.loads(data)
    file.close()
```